# How do you get site specific search autocomplete in the url bar?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

Certain sites provide site specific autocomplete results in the chrome url bar when you do a tab search (by typing in the base url and pressing tab). This isn't the browser history autocomplete, they're suggestions from the site, and includes results of things never searched.

For example, wikipedia.org will provide autocomplete suggestions when doing a tab search.

[image]

Here's an example with a more specific dataset:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenSearch file allows you to add a custom search engine listing (on your own site) through the search feature that appears in all modern browsers. All of the major browsers can take advantage of OpenSearch: http://www.opensearch.org/

Implement local search, then add it to the header:

```
<link rel="search"
           type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" 
           href="http://example.com/content-search.xml"
           title="Content search" />
```

If this is implemented then type URL press TAB and you will be able to search using the site search.

Comment: The link is broken. The correct one is https://www.opensearch.org/

Comment: @orgads fixed the link.